# Flaggin active customers - Atleast one transaction every month

Tags: sql, hive

Once the customer is registered, between date_registered and current date - if the customer has made atleast one transaction every month, then flag it as active or else flag it has inactive

Note: Every customer has different date_registered

I tried this but doesn't work since few of the customers were onboarded in the middle of the year
Eg -

```
-------------------------------------
txn_id | txn_date | name | amount
-------------------------------------
101     2018-05-01  ABC    100
102     2018-05-02  ABC    200
-------------------------------------
```

```
       (case when count(distinct case when txn_date >= '2018-05-01' and txn_date < '2019-06-01' then last_day(txn_date) end) = 13
             then 'active' else 'inactive'
        end) as flag
from t;
```

Final output

```
----------------
name | flag
----------------
ABC    active
BCF    inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtering on an aggregation query:

```
select customer,
       count(distinct last_day(txn_date)) as num_months
from (select t.*, min(date_registered) over (partition by customer) as min_dr
      from t
     ) t
group by customer, min_dr
having count(distinct last_day(txn_date)) = months_between(last_day(current_date), last_day(min_dr)) + 1;
```

Note:  This may give unexpected results toward the beginning of a month, if customers do not all have transactions on the first day of the month.

EDIT:

If you want a flag, just move the `HAVING` logic to the `SELECT`:

```
select customer,
       (case when count(distinct last_day(txn_date)) = months_between(last_day(current_date), last_day(min_dr)) + 1
             then 'Active' else 'Inactive'
        end) as active_flag
from (select t.*, min(date_registered) over (partition by customer) as min_dr
      from t
     ) t
group by customer, min_dr;
```

Comment: Thanks gordon.
Is it possible where for any given customer, between min(trn_date) & max(trn_date) if he/she was active every month then flag as "Active" else flag as "Inactive"?

Comment: Hi is it possible to write this query in Prestodb? 
Considering last_day & months_between functions are not available

Comment: @NamanDoshi . . . If you have a question about PrestoDB, then you should ask a *new* question.  This question is quite clearly about Hive.